# Building a recursive delete function (in php)

Tags: php, recursion

Here's the deal. I've got a "tree" or a "subtree" that I want to navigate and delete every element in. Each "node" may contain links to other nodes below it (no problem) OR may contain links OUTSIDE that particular "tree"/"subtree". How can I build a function that only deletes "within" the specified tree?

Comment: you might want to give an example structure and desired output

Comment: Give an example of your "tree" and how the deletion should operate.

Comment: I doubt it's homework when it's late June.

Comment: if a node points to another node, then the 'another' node is part of the tree. OR - what about nodes in other trees that point to the nodes you'd be deleting?? maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same recursive delete that you're used to.  You just have to keep your links separated - one list for in-tree links, one for out-of-tree links.  Alternately, you can have a flag that keeps track of the in-tree/out-of-tree state for each link - but you're going to have to distinguish when you make the link.

Answer (score 0):

you need [RecursiveIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php)

Comment: The link may be useful, but some brief explanation would make the answer more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `realpath()`:

```
function DeleteTree($path)
{
    if (is_dir($path) === true)
    {
        $path = realpath($path);
        $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = realpath($path . '/' . $file);

            // file is within tree
            if (substr($file, 0, strlen($path)) == $path)
            {
                DeleteTree($file);
            }
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    }

    else if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        return unlink($path);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The above should do what you're looking for.

---

Oh... I just realized this may not be related to the filesystem... The fault is all yours! :P